# xsl code problem when running Java code related to data conversion

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to run a Java code, that is related to converting xml to csv.
The use of an xsl file is necessary. However, some problems seem to exist in the code, because when running the Java code I am receiving an empty csv file (with only title of each column present). The Java code works really fine, because I used it with some test data.

So the problem is reggarding the xsl file.

My xml file looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <fcd-export xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/fcd_file.xsd">
        <data time="0.00">
            <mobil id="1" x="23.774532" y="37.967331" angle="229.707852" type="car" speed="0.000000" pos="5.100000" lane="32041497_0" slope="0.000000"/>
            <mobil id="2" x="23.758638" y="37.971738" angle="38.291786" type="car" speed="0.000000" pos="5.100000" lane="265887574#0_0" slope="0.000000"/>
        </data>
        <data time="1.00">
            <mobil id="1" x="23.774522" y="37.967326" angle="230.554332" type="car" speed="1.000000" pos="6.100000" lane="32041497_0" slope="0.000000"/>
            <mobil id="2" x="23.758645" y="37.971745" angle="38.291786" type="car" speed="1.000000" pos="6.100000" lane="265887574#0_0" slope="0.000000"/>
        </data>
        <data time="2.00">
            <mobil id="1" x="23.774503" y="37.967316" angle="233.076683" type="car" speed="2.000000" pos="8.100000" lane="32041497_0" slope="0.000000"/>
            <mobil id="2" x="23.758660" y="37.971759" angle="38.291786" type="car" speed="2.000000" pos="8.100000" lane="265887574#0_0" slope="0.000000"/>
        </data>
```

While my xsl file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    x
    <xsl:for-each select="/data">
    <xsl:value-of select="/data/mobil/@x" />
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I want is to declare in lines 5-7 that I want the values of the attribute: x of mobil etiquette.

Comment: **1.** Your XML file seems cut off: There is no closing tag for `fcd-export`. **2.** If `fcd-export` is the root element, then your XSLT will not do anything, because it assumes `data` is the root element.

Comment: well, actually, i mean in the real file there is </fcd-export> in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your input actually looks like:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fcd-export xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/fcd_file.xsd">
    <data time="0.00">
        <mobil id="1" x="23.774532" y="37.967331" angle="229.707852" type="car" speed="0.000000" pos="5.100000" lane="32041497_0" slope="0.000000"/>
        <mobil id="2" x="23.758638" y="37.971738" angle="38.291786" type="car" speed="0.000000" pos="5.100000" lane="265887574#0_0" slope="0.000000"/>
    </data>
    <data time="1.00">
        <mobil id="1" x="23.774522" y="37.967326" angle="230.554332" type="car" speed="1.000000" pos="6.100000" lane="32041497_0" slope="0.000000"/>
        <mobil id="2" x="23.758645" y="37.971745" angle="38.291786" type="car" speed="1.000000" pos="6.100000" lane="265887574#0_0" slope="0.000000"/>
    </data>
    <data time="2.00">
        <mobil id="1" x="23.774503" y="37.967316" angle="233.076683" type="car" speed="2.000000" pos="8.100000" lane="32041497_0" slope="0.000000"/>
        <mobil id="2" x="23.758660" y="37.971759" angle="38.291786" type="car" speed="2.000000" pos="8.100000" lane="265887574#0_0" slope="0.000000"/>
    </data>
</fcd-export>
```

you can use the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/fcd-export">
    <xsl:for-each select="data/mobil">
        <xsl:value-of select="@x"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result:**

```
23.774532
23.758638
23.774522
23.758645
23.774503
23.758660
```

---

Note the use of `<xsl:for-each select="data/mobil">` instead `<xsl:for-each select="/data">`. The latter tries to select a root element named `data` which does not exist. And also `<xsl:value-of select="@x"/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="/data/mobil/@x" />`. Your version (if it worked) would only get the value from the first `mobil`.